# How to use Chrome Devtools without ADB?

Tags: google-chrome, adb, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to use Google Chrome DevTools without ADB. But I probably made a mistake, because when I don't use ADB, the page "about:inspect" says:

> "No device detected"

. I tried to verify if I had the good usb driver, but it seems that all is ok. 
On my Device Manager, I can see `"Mobile Devices -> GT-I9300"` and `"Samsung Android Phone->Samsung Android ADB Interface"`
When I try to click on "update driver", it says :

> "your driver is on date"

I installed Chrome on Android Beta (v34) on my mobile (a Samsung Galaxy S3), and I use Chrome V33 on my computer with Windows 7.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For more information on how to do this check this out https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#setting-up-device

You may have missed a step, or may not have a supported device.

Comment: Followed this and my chrome does not detect a Galaxy Nexus and a Galaxy Tab 3... "no device detected"